# maven WAR plugin skips resources?

Tags: maven, war

Now this is downright bizarre: I have a number of folders/files I want copied into my WAR, here's the relevant part of the POM:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
      <webResources>
        <resource><directory>../common-web-content/src/main/resources</directory></resource>
        <resource><directory>../pqm-web-content/src/main/resources</directory><filtering>true</filtering></resource>
        <resource><directory>../common-presentation/src/main/webapp</directory></resource>
        <resource>
          <directory>${project.basedir}/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF</directory>
          <includes><include>web.xml</include></includes>
          <filtering>true</filtering>
          <targetPath>WEB-INF</targetPath>
        </resource>
      </webResources>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

The paths are all correct and double-checked. However, **the *second* resource folder is not copied** - in this case pqm-web-content, but even if I change the sequence, it's always the second one that's missing. But there is no error message:

```
[INFO] Processing war project
[INFO] Copy webapp webResources[D:\pqmGF\pqm\pqm-war\../common-web-content/src/main/resources] to[D:\pqmGF\pqm\pqm-war\target\pqm-war-3.3.5.0-SNAPSHOT]
[INFO] Copy webapp webResources[D:\pqmGF\pqm\pqm-war\../pqm-web-content/src/main/resources] to[D:\pqmGF\pqm\pqm-war\target\pqm-war-3.3.5.0-SNAPSHOT]
[INFO] Copy webapp webResources[D:\pqmGF\pqm\pqm-war\../common-presentation/src/main/webapp] to[D:\pqmGF\pqm\pqm-war\target\pqm-war-3.3.5.0-SNAPSHOT]
[INFO] Copy webapp webResources[D:\pqmGF\pqm\pqm-war/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF] to [D:\pqmGF\pqm\pqm-war\target\pqm-war-3.3.5.0-SNAPSHOT]
[INFO] Webapp assembled in[7891 msecs]
```

Comment: Have you try removing the fitering tag?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently, this is a bug of Maven or incompatibility between Maven 3.0.3 and the WAR Plugin. After switching to Maven 2.2.1, it works correctly.

Comment: I did a quick search of the Maven-WAR JIRA and did not see anything that looked like this.  You may want to file an issue so the right folks see the problem and resolve it.

Answer (score 1):

have you considered doing something like this...

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
      <webResources>
        <resource><directory>../common-web-content/src/main/resources</directory></resource>
        <!-- this next line is repeated because of a problem I am having with the maven-war-plugin -->
        <resource><directory>../pqm-web-content/src/main/resources</directory><filtering>true</filtering></resource>
        <resource><directory>../pqm-web-content/src/main/resources</directory><filtering>true</filtering></resource>
        <resource><directory>../common-presentation/src/main/webapp</directory></resource>
        <resource>
          <directory>${project.basedir}/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF</directory>
          <includes><include>web.xml</include></includes>
          <filtering>true</filtering>
          <targetPath>WEB-INF</targetPath>
        </resource>
      </webResources>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: I'll accept this for creativity, though for some reason the original problem has disappeared, so I can't say whether it would have fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem with `maven-war-plugin version 2.6` when from two consecutive directories, first's contents would not be copied to final build.
Problem was that I had two `<directory>` tags in single `<resource>` tag. Single `<resource>` with single `<directory>` tag worked fine.