# Copying jar files maven project in webapp folder

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, jboss, applet

I am trying to copy few jar files from **web-inf/lib** folder to **src/main/webapp/applet** folder which are all the required
archive for applets so that jar files present in the output war file.

I want this copy operation need to be performed during maven build.Already I tried two options one with

**maven-war-plugin**  which goes below.

```
<webResources>
    <resource>      
        <directory>src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/lib</directory>
        <filtering>true</filtering>
        <includes>
            <include>**/*.jar</include>
        </includes>
        <targetPath>${basedir}/src/main/webapp/applet</targetPath>
    </resource>
</webResources>
```

and the trace of the build goes below.

```
[INFO] --- maven-war-plugin:2.6:war (default-war) @ myapp ---
[INFO] Packaging webapp
[INFO] Assembling webapp [myapp] in [C:\jboss_projects\myapp\src\main\webapp]
[INFO] Processing war project
[INFO] Copying webapp webResources [C:\jboss_projects\myapp\src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/lib] to [C:\jboss_projects\myapp\src\main\webapp]
[INFO] Webapp assembled in [999 msecs]
[INFO] Building war: C:\jboss_projects\myapp\target\myapp.war
```

The next try is with **maven-resources-plugin** which goes below.

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.6</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>copy-resources</id>
            <phase>validate</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>copy-resources</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <outputDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/webapp/applet</outputDirectory>
                <overwrite>true</overwrite>
                <resources>
                    <resource>
                        <directory>src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/lib</directory>
                        <filtering>true</filtering>
                        <includes>
                            <include>**/*.jar</include>
                        </includes>
                    </resource>
                </resources>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

> Note: in both trials I found the applet folder created inside webapp
>   while updating project but during build that folder is not
>   modified/created.

Any advice would be much appreciated.Please don't mark this as a duplicate every reference i looked into helps how to copy from a source to web-inf/lib folder.
not this one.

Comment: I guess you should copy to the output (target) folder, not the source folder.

Comment: @jeroen_de_schutter with which one i should try this? war plugin or resource plugin ?Moreover while package .war it will look in to src/main/webapp only..will it look into target folder?

Comment: I would choose a third option: using the dependency plugin: https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/copy-mojo.html and the copy goal. Then bind it to the package phase. 
You need to be careful when turning on filtering when you copy jar files, they may get corrupted. Filtering does not filter the copied files, it filters their contents.

Comment: Why don't you put files in required folder in the first place?

Comment: @AleksandrM It is a multi module project.So jars which I am looking to copy...which are all the dependent project for this one..so i can not put files in the folder as a static libraries

Comment: @wemu thanks for the third option.will look into that.?But I could not understand the things you mentioned about filtering.Being said that,I want to find out what I am doing wrong with war plugin webresources paramater.In the trace you could it tries to copy from web-inf/lib but it destination is wrong?Can you explain this too.

Comment: So you want to build jars and after that copy them to some folder?

Comment: @AleksandrM yeah correct...those jar modules are added as dependencies for this project.since applet archive cannot look into web-inf/lib folder I want these jar as a duplicate inside webapp also.

Comment: [Maven-war-plugin bug with maven 3.0.3 apparently 2.2.1 does not have this explained more in the link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5993057/maven-war-plugin-skips-resources) explains why maven-war-plugin fails to copy files to the destination.This is a bug with maven.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

wemu suggestion worked.This is how it is configured to get the dependent jars from local repo.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${maven-dependency-plugin.version}</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>applet-dependencies</id>
            <phase>prepare-package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>copy</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <artifactItems>                                 
                    <artifactItem>
                        <groupId>com.xxx.yyy</groupId>
                        <artifactId>yyy</artifactId>
                        <version>1.0</version>
                        <type>jar</type>
                        <overWrite>true</overWrite>
                        <outputDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/webapp/applet</outputDirectory>
                        <destFileName>yyy.jar</destFileName>
                    </artifactItem>
                </artifactItems>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check whether below ant task works for you ?

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.7</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>move-applet-jar-files</id>
                    <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>run</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <target name="Copying jar files for applets">
                            <echo message="your jar file to be copied" />
                            <copy file="${source.dir}/abc.jar" tofile="${target.dir}/abc.jar" />
                        </target>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```